# What is the best way to download all NFTs data

Tags: web3-providers, nft, erc-1155

Mb someone knows what is the best way to download all NFTs data(uri) from contract?? I try to use filter on minting event but I need to do N iterations, because infura or web3 has limitation of 10k events in response. In this way it is not very efficient solution. Mb there are some other ways to do it?

P.S nft erc1155

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution would be that you set up your own local Ethereum node, and filter all the transactions of this contract. Let's suppose the contract was created at block X of the Ethereum blockchain, then once your node is fully synced you can filter transactions from the transaction in which the contracted was created in block x till the present date. This will reduce some of the parsing time as compared to if you start parsing from the genesis block of Ethereum.